# OpenERP custom report filename

Tags: openerp-7

I would like to customize reports filename.

For instance, when I download an invoice, I will have something like 'Invoice.pdf' as filename. What I would like is something like 'invoice_number.pdf' but I don't know how to use dynamic file name ?

Comment: see http://forum.openerp.com/forum/topic24051.html  it's close to what you want..

Comment: Not really satisfactory, ask too much work for a company like the one I'm am working for

Comment: yes it can be done as you want. like invoice_1234, invoice_1235 etc..

Answer (score 2):

I found a way for 7.0 and current trunk:

1. For a quick fix, take a look at the Reports class in:

   ```
   openerp-7.0\web\addons\web\controllers\main.py
   ```
2. The report name is set in a variable named file_name:

   ```
   file_name = '%s.%s' % (file_name, report_struct['format'])
   ```
3. Find this line and insert this part before it:

   ```
   '''
     YP: Added proc. to create reports with real object names (the object must have a field named "name"):
     eg: "PO00006.pdf" instead of "Request For Quotation.pdf" for a single object report
         "PO00006-PO00002.pdf" instead of "Request For Quotation.pdf" for a multiple objects report
   '''

   # Try to get current object model and their ids from context
   if action.has_key('context'):
       action_context = action.get('context',{})
       if action_context.has_key('active_model') and action_context.has_key('active_id'):
           action_active_model = action_context.get('active_model','')
           action_active_ids = action_context.get('active_ids', [])
           if action_active_model and action_active_ids:
               # Use built-in ORM method to get data from DB
               m = req.session.model(action_active_model)
               r = m.read(action_active_ids, False, context)
               # Parse result to create a better filename
               for i, item in enumerate(r):
                 if item.has_key('name'):
                   if i == 0: 
                     file_name = ('%s') % (item['name'])
                   else:
                     file_name = ('%s-%s') % (file_name, item['name'])
   ```

Answer (score 1):

1. For a quick fix, take a look at the Reports class in:

   ```
   openerp-6.1\web\addons\web\controllers\main.py
   ```
2. The report name is set in a variable named header.
   For my needs, I only want the report to be named by the object name (that's suitable in 99% of cases) so I added a new variable named report_name:

   ```
   report_name = action['report_name']
   if action.has_key('context'):
       action_context = action.get('context',{})
       if action_context.has_key('name'):
           report_name = action_context['name'] 

   return req.make_response(report,
        headers=[
            ('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s.%s"' % (report_name, report_struct['format'])),
            ('Content-Type', report_mimetype),
            ('Content-Length', len(report))],
        cookies={'fileToken': int(token)})
   ```

Comment: Is this also for OpenERP 7 ?

Comment: No because the context does not have the current object in context anymore

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to set the default filename like the attach file name, using the expression in the attachment attribute in your xml report definition.

Found and modify this file: openerp7/openerp-web/addons/web/controllers/main.py.

Search this sentence:

```
        file_name = '%s.%s' % (file_name, report_struct['format'])
```

Then add this code before:

```
    '''Code added by Raul Paz to set the default file_name like the attach_name
        The attach_name mach with the attachment expresion from your report_xml
        <report
            id="report_webkit.YourModule_report_id"
            model="YourModule.model"        
            name="Your_report_name"
            file="YOUR_MODULE/report/YOUR_MAKO_FILE.mako"
            string="Your Text in the print button" 
            auto="False" 
            report_type="webkit"
            attachment="'Valid_filename_expresion"
            usage="default"
        />
        And
        to modify existing report sale_report.xml to manage the name:
        create in your module a file : sale_report.xml
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <openerp>
           <data>
              <record id="sale.report_sale_order" model="ir.actions.report.xml">
                  <field name="attachment">(object.name or 'Sale Order')</field>
          <field name="attachment_use" eval="True"/>
      </record>
          </data>
        </openerp>

    '''
    try:
        if action.get('attachment_use',False) and action['attachment']:
            model = context['active_model']
            cr = openerp.pooler.get_db(req.session._db).cursor()
            uid = context['uid']
            ids = context['active_ids']
            objects=openerp.pooler.get_pool(req.session._db).get(model).browse(cr,uid,ids,context=context)
            file_name=[eval(action['attachment'],{'object':x, 'time':time}) for x in objects][0]
    except:
        pass
    #end code added
```

Good luky